# R Shiny: Apply Code to Input File

Tags: r, csv, input, shiny

I have a task to build a shiny app.

I have a predefined list with rules in R readable language, called "vrList".

Example:
vrList$Formula[1]:

```
abs(cube$C08.02[,04] + cube$C08.02[,05]) <= cube$C08.02[,02]
```

cube is list of dataframes.
Each dataframe of the cube (called "C08.02" in this case) is a sheet, which shall be built by the user's input.

The user loads up a csv, which shall be transformed to a matrix in [STEP 1] as follows
and the rules from vrList shall be applied to the matrix in [STEP 2].

I just want to build the bridge into the shiny world.

My shiny code looks as follows so far:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "sparkasse_web.css")),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "sparkasse_serif_web.css")),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap.min.css")),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")),

  fileInput("file1", "Upload file",
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv")),

  actionButton("eval","Evaluate Input"),

  tableOutput("eval_result"),

  tags$head(tags$style("#eval_result{color: black;
                                 font-size: 11px;
                                 font-style: bold;
                                background-color: lightgrey
                                 }"
  )
  )


)

# server #####################################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {

  # INPUT ######################################################


  csv <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df<- read.csv2(inFile$datapath, header=T)
    return(df)



    # STEP 1 ###################################################


# create matrix from table
  matrix <- matrix(nrow=99, ncol=99) 

# rownames
  x <- paste("r0",seq(10,90,10),sep="")
  y <- paste("r",seq(100,990,10),sep="")
  rownames(matrix) <- c(x,y)

# colnames
  x <- paste("c0",seq(10,90,10),sep="")
  y <- paste("c",seq(100,990,10),sep="")
  colnames(matrix) <- c(x,y)

# rownr and colnr
  table$r/10 -> row
  table$c/10 -> col

# fill matrix with real data
  for(i in 1:nrow(table)){
    matrix[row[i],col[i]] <- table$x[i]
  }                 

# bring to list
cube$08.02 <- matrix

  })



  # OUTPUT #####################################################

  output$eval <- renderText({
    validate(need(!is.null(csv()),'No upload!'))



      # STEP 2 ###################################################  

# here the rules shall be applied to input data to check if the rules can be approved.

for (i in 1:nrow(vrList$Formula)){
      vrList$valid[i]<-(mean(eval(parse(text=vrListSt$Formula[i])))==TRUE)

print(vrList)   



  })


}
```

The code has to run through the data dependant from user's input.
Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks.
Sven

Comment: Seems like you are on the right path, I am just a little confused on the question. What from the user's input is the "dependent" part?

Comment: I just wanted to say that the code has to react on the user's Input.

Comment: Hello, can anyone offer a solution? Thanks for help.